# Simulation and Scenarios in R + help for function

Tags: r, simulation

Suppose that I have the following.

A table with input data

```
table <- data.frame(id=c(1,2,3,4,5,6),
                      cost=c(100,200,300,400,500,600))
```

A list of possible outcomes with and associate probability

```
values<-list(c(1),
             c(0.5),
             c(0))
```

A simulation of different scenarios

```
esc<-sample(1:3,100,replace=T)
```

How can I add a new column which contains the next formula?

```
id cost final
1  100  100*ifelse(esc[1]==1,values[[1]],ifelse(esc[1]==2,values[[2]],values[[3]]))
2  200  200*ifelse(esc[2]==1,values[[1]],ifelse(esc[2]==2,values[[2]],values[[3]]))
```

Comment: I think you need to learn R first before asking such a fundamental question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Convert `esc` variable into factor by using `values` as labels. Then convert into numeric type. This will map `values` to `esc` correctly.

```
esc <- as.numeric ( as.character( factor( esc, levels = sort( unique( esc )), labels = values) ) )
# [1] 1.0 0.5 0.5 0.0 1.0 0.0 0.0 0.5 0.5 1.0 1.0 1.0 0.0 0.5 0.0 0.5 0.0 0.0 0.5 0.0 0.0 1.0 0.5 1.0 1.0 0.5 1.0 0.5 0.0 0.5 0.5 0.5 0.5 1.0 0.0 0.0 0.0
# [38] 1.0 0.0 0.5 0.0 0.5 0.0 0.5 0.5 0.0 1.0 0.5 0.0 0.0 0.5 0.0 0.5 1.0 1.0 1.0 1.0 0.5 0.5 0.5 0.0 1.0 0.5 1.0 0.5 1.0 0.5 0.0 1.0 0.0 0.5 0.0 0.5 0.5
# [75] 0.5 0.0 0.0 0.5 0.0 0.0 0.5 0.0 0.5 1.0 0.0 1.0 0.0 1.0 1.0 1.0 1.0 1.0 0.5 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.5 0.5 0.0 0.5

table$esc <- esc[ 1: nrow(table) ]   # add esc to table
```

Now multiply `cost` with `esc` to get `final`

```
within( table, final <- cost * esc)
#   id cost esc final
# 1  1  100 1.0   100
# 2  2  200 0.5   100
# 3  3  300 0.5   150
# 4  4  400 0.0     0
# 5  5  500 1.0   500
# 6  6  600 0.0     0
```

Data:

```
table <- data.frame(id=c(1,2,3,4,5,6), cost=c(100,200,300,400,500,600))
values <- c(1, 0.5, 0)
set.seed(1L)
esc <- sample(1:3,100,replace=T)
esc
# [1] 1 2 2 3 1 3 3 2 2 1 1 1 3 2 3 2 3 3 2 3 3 1 2 1 1 2 1 2 3 2 2 2 2 1 3 3 3 1 3 2 3 2 3 2 2 3 1 2 3 3 2 3 2 1 1 1 1 2 2 2 3 1 2 1 2 1 2 3 1 3 2 3 2 2 2
# [76] 3 3 2 3 3 2 3 2 1 3 1 3 1 1 1 1 1 2 3 3 3 2 2 3 2
```

Comment: Thank you!, easier what I was thinking.